# Using the dask labextenstion to connect to a remote cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, jupyter, dask, amazon-emr

I'm interested in running a Dask cluster on EMR and interacting with it from inside of a Jupyter Lab notebook running on a *separate* EC2 instance (e.g. an EC2 instance not within the cluster and not managed by EMR).

The Dask documentation points to [`dask-labextension`](https://github.com/dask/dask-labextension) as the tool of choice for this use case. `dask-labextension` relies on [a YAML config file](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/configuration.html) (and/or some environment vars) to understand how to talk to the cluster. However, as far as I can tell, this configuration can only be set to point to a *local* Dask cluster. In other words, you must be in a Jupyter Lab notebook running on an instance within the cluster (presumably on the master instance?) in order to use this extension.

Is my read correct? Is it not currently possible to use `dask-labextension` with an external Dask cluster?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you get lab to work with EMR.  I keep getting a bootstrap failure when I try to load with `sudo initctl start jupyter-lab`.  Did you get this to work with @MRocklin answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dask Labextension can talk to any Dask cluster that is visible from where your web client is running.  If you can connect to a dashboard in a web browser then you can copy that same address to the Dask-Labextension search bar and it will connect.

Comment: What if it does not connect?